# How to make Bootstrap header item and dropdown-menu the same width?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have this header in my Bootstrap template:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            //Some unrelated stuff
        </div>

        <div id="navbar" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                //Some unrelated stuff          
            </ul>

            <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right-custom">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">DDButtonText <strong class="caret"></strong></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        Test
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

What I'm trying to accomplish is to make the dropdown menu the same width as the 'DDButtonText' thing. I tried setting min-width to dropdown-menu but it was different for each browser. It was alright in my Firefox but Chrome and other browsers showed a little different sizes.

How do I make my menu be the same size as the button regardless of browser, always?

Comment: Flex:0 0 50%; on each of them and display:flex; on their container

Answer (score 2):

You can try adding this:

**CSS**:

```
.nav .dropdown-menu{
    width: 100%;
    min-width: inherit;
}
```

**Bootply**: http://www.bootply.com/MfkTjxasD7